How can I ensure that emojis are displayed correctly in PDF filenames and its content?
I am using iText to handle different fonts and emojis, but the emojis are not displaying as expected. They are being removed completely instead.
These are my dependencies
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.2</log4j2.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <itext.version>8.0.5</itext.version>
    </properties>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- always needed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>io</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- always needed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for forms -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for PDF/A -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for digital signatures -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for barcodes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for Asian fonts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for hyphenation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        

 private static final float MARGIN_X = 50;
    private static final float MARGIN_Y = 50;
    private static final float FONT_SIZE = 12;
    private static final float LINE_HEIGHT = 1.5f * FONT_SIZE;

    private static final String EMOJI_FONT_PATH = "static/NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf";
    private BaseFont emojiBaseFont;
    private Font emojiFont;
    private Font normalFont;
    private Font boldFont;
    private Font italicFont;
    private Font monospaceFont;
    private List<Message> messages;
    private String ticketNumber;
    private String issuedTime;
    private String closedTime;
    private String clientWhatsAppNumber;
    private String customerWhatsAppNumber;
    private String agentName;
    private String customerName;
    private String lastOutgoingMessageTime;
    private String fileName;
    private Font fallbackFont;

    public ChatTranscriptServiceImpl(ChatParticipantClient chatParticipantClient) {
        this.chatParticipantClient = chatParticipantClient;
    }

    @Override
    public ChatTranscriptResponse downloadChatTranscript(String chatParticipantId) {
        this.messages = chatParticipantClient.getMessagesByChatParticipant(chatParticipantId);
        byte[] pdfBytes = processMessages();

        ChatTranscriptResponse response = new ChatTranscriptResponse();
        response.setPdfBytes(pdfBytes);
        response.setFilename(fileName);
        return response;
    }

    private byte[] processMessages() {
        Pattern ticketNumberPattern = Pattern.compile("Your (?:previous )?ticket number is (.*?) please retain the ticket number to reference this chat.", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Pattern ratingMessagePattern = Pattern.compile("Please rate our service.");

        for (Message message : this.messages) {
            processTicketNumber(ticketNumberPattern, message);
            processOutgoingMessage(message);
            processRatingMessage(ratingMessagePattern, message);
            extractWhatsAppNumbers(message);
        }

        return finalizeTranscript();
    }

    private void processTicketNumber(Pattern pattern, Message message) {
        String text = message.getText();

        if (text != null) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                ticketNumber = matcher.group(1).trim();
                issuedTime = formatDateTime(message.getCreatedTime());
            } else if (issuedTime == null) {
                issuedTime = formatDateTime(message.getCreatedTime());
            }
        } else if (issuedTime == null) {
            issuedTime = formatDateTime(message.getCreatedTime());
        }
    }

    private void processOutgoingMessage(Message message) {
        if (Pl4ChatMessageDirection.OUTGOING.equals(message.getDirection())) {
            lastOutgoingMessageTime = formatDateTime(message.getCreatedTime());

            if (message.getAgent() != null) {
                agentName = getAgentName(message.getAgent());
            } else {
                agentName = "Bot";
            }

            if (message.getChatParticipant() != null) {
                customerName = getCustomerName(message.getChatParticipant());
            }
        }
    }

    private void processRatingMessage(Pattern pattern, Message message) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message.getText());
        if (matcher.find()) {
            closedTime = formatDateTime(message.getCreatedTime());
        } else if (message.getChatParticipant() != null && message.getChatParticipant().isConversationClosed()) {
            closedTime = lastOutgoingMessageTime != null ? lastOutgoingMessageTime : "Open";
        } else {
            closedTime = "Open";
        }
    }

    private void extractWhatsAppNumbers(Message message) {
        if (clientWhatsAppNumber == null && message.getChatParticipant() != null && message.getChatParticipant().getWhatsAppClientNumber() != null) {
            clientWhatsAppNumber = message.getChatParticipant().getWhatsAppClientNumber();
        }

        if (customerWhatsAppNumber == null && message.getChatParticipant() != null && message.getChatParticipant().getPhoneNumber() != null) {
            customerWhatsAppNumber = message.getChatParticipant().getPhoneNumber();
        }
    }

    private String getAgentName(SystemUser agent) {
        if (agent.getFirstName() != null && agent.getLastName() != null) {
            return agent.getFirstName() + " " + agent.getLastName();
        } else if (agent.getFirstName() != null) {
            return agent.getFirstName();
        } else if (agent.getLastName() != null) {
            return agent.getLastName();
        }
        return "Bot";
    }

    private String getCustomerName(ChatParticipant participant) {
        if (participant.getFullName() != null) {
            return participant.getFullName();
        } else if (participant.getFirstName() != null && participant.getLastName() != null) {
            return participant.getFirstName() + " " + participant.getLastName();
        } else if (participant.getFirstName() != null) {
            return participant.getFirstName();
        } else if (participant.getLastName() != null) {
            return participant.getLastName();
        }
        return "Unknown";
    }

    private byte[] finalizeTranscript() {
        try {
            return this.generatePdfTranscript();
        } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
            log.error("Error generating file: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw CustomParameterizedException.singleParameterProblem(
                    String.format("Error generating transcript... %n%s", e.getMessage()),
                    Status.BAD_REQUEST
            );
        }
    }

    private byte[] generatePdfTranscript() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, MARGIN_X, MARGIN_X, MARGIN_Y, MARGIN_Y);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);

        document.open();

        initializeFonts();

        setupPdfHeader(document);
        addTranscriptTitle(document);

        for (Message message : messages) {
            addMessage(document, writer, message);
        }

        document.close();

        fileName = sanitizeFilename("chat_transcript_" + ticketNumber + ".pdf");
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    private void setupPdfHeader(Document document) throws DocumentException {
        Font headerFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, FONT_SIZE, Font.BOLD);

        Paragraph header = new Paragraph();
        header.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

        if (ticketNumber != null) {
            header.add(new Chunk("Ticket Number: " + ticketNumber + "\n", headerFont));
            header.add(new Chunk("Date & Time Ticket Issued: " + issuedTime + "\n", headerFont));
            header.add(new Chunk("Date & Time Ticket Closed: " + closedTime + "\n", headerFont));
        } else {
            header.add(new Chunk("No ticket issued\n", headerFont));
        }

        if (clientWhatsAppNumber != null) {
            header.add(new Chunk("Service's WhatsApp number: " + clientWhatsAppNumber + "\n", headerFont));
        }

        if (customerWhatsAppNumber != null) {
            header.add(new Chunk("Customer's WhatsApp number: " + customerWhatsAppNumber + "\n", headerFont));
        }

        header.add(new Chunk("Agent's Name & Surname: " + agentName + "\n", headerFont));
        header.add(new Chunk("Customer's Name & Surname: " + customerName + "\n", headerFont));

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(header);
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
        cell.setPadding(10);
        table.addCell(cell);

        document.add(table);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    }

    private void addTranscriptTitle(Document document) throws DocumentException {
        Font titleFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, FONT_SIZE + 2, Font.BOLD);
        Paragraph title = new Paragraph("Ticket Transcript:", titleFont);
        title.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        document.add(title);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    }


    private Font getFontForPart(ProcessedPart part) {
        switch (part.style) {
            case "bold":
                return boldFont;
            case "italic":
                return italicFont;
            case "monospace":
                return monospaceFont;
            default:
                return normalFont;
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmoji(int codePoint) {
        return (codePoint >= 0x1F300 && codePoint <= 0x1F9FF) ||
                (codePoint >= 0x2600 && codePoint <= 0x26FF) ||
                (codePoint >= 0x2700 && codePoint <= 0x27BF) ||
                (codePoint >= 0xFE00 && codePoint <= 0xFE0F) ||
                (codePoint >= 0x1F900 && codePoint <= 0x1F9FF);
    }

    private void addMessage(Document document, PdfWriter writer, Message message) throws DocumentException {
        String sender = message.getDirection().equals(Pl4ChatMessageDirection.OUTGOING) ? agentName : customerName;
        String messageText = sender + ": " + message.getText();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setPadding(10);
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
        cell.setBackgroundColor(message.getDirection().equals(Pl4ChatMessageDirection.OUTGOING) ?
                new BaseColor(220, 220, 220) : new BaseColor(220, 248, 198));

        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        addMixedTextToParagraph(paragraph, messageText);

        cell.addElement(paragraph);
        table.addCell(cell);
        document.add(table);

        addTimestamp(document, message);
    }

    private void addTimestamp(Document document, Message message) throws DocumentException {
        String timeString = formatDateTime(message.getCreatedTime());
        Paragraph timestamp = new Paragraph(timeString, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8));
        timestamp.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        document.add(timestamp);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    }

    private String formatDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        return dateTime != null ? dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) : "N/A";
    }

    private void initializeFonts() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        normalFont = new Font(baseFont, FONT_SIZE);
        boldFont = new Font(baseFont, FONT_SIZE, Font.BOLD);
        italicFont = new Font(baseFont, FONT_SIZE, Font.ITALIC);
        monospaceFont = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), FONT_SIZE);

        InputStream emojiFontStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(EMOJI_FONT_PATH);
        if (emojiFontStream == null) {
            throw new IOException("Emoji font file not found in resources");
        }
        byte[] emojiFontBytes = emojiFontStream.readAllBytes();
        emojiBaseFont = BaseFont.createFont(EMOJI_FONT_PATH, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, emojiFontBytes, null);
        emojiFont = new Font(emojiBaseFont, FONT_SIZE);
    }

    private void addMixedTextToParagraph(Paragraph paragraph, String text) {
        List<ProcessedPart> parts = processText(text);
        for (ProcessedPart part : parts) {
            Font font = getFontForPart(part);
            for (int i = 0; i < part.text.length(); i++) {
                int codePoint = part.text.codePointAt(i);
                String charString = new String(Character.toChars(codePoint));
                Font charFont = isEmoji(codePoint) ? emojiFont : font;
                Chunk chunk = new Chunk(charString, charFont);
                paragraph.add(chunk);

                if (Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint(codePoint)) {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            if (part.lineBreak > 0) {
                paragraph.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            }
        }
    }

I tried displaying emojis as they are in the PDF document, but it is returning blank spaces where the emojis should be: '    Esphi N  ' instead of 'Esphi N'. However, when I copy and paste the text with the empty spaces into Google, the emojis display properly

I am confused. Is this a question about file systems or is this a question about PDF document content? Those are two very different things. Your title is about one, your prose is about another.

Far too much code. Min. Rep. Please

The least you should do is use a font that includes emojis. And when then I doubt that colored emojis are supported. Consider updating iText, though: you use the old version 7.0.4 while text is soon going for 9.0.0.

@Basil Bourque
Yes, this is about PDF document content, apologies for not specifying.
